# How to interpret result from mvpart object in R?

Tags: r, interpretation, cart

I used R [mvpart](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvpart/index.html) package to create a multivariate regression tree. This is part of the output:

```
          CP               nsplit         rel error    xerror       xstd
1       0.02717093      0         1.0000000 1.0005358 0.03481409
2       0.01302184      2         0.9456581 0.9521266 0.03306820

Node number 1: 3479 observations,    complexity param=0.02717093
Means=12.94,0.5749,9.375,0.72,1.611,0.973,2.153,0.6209,3.307,3.702,2.422,0.3837,1.499,     Summed MSE=1305.19 
left son=2 (992 obs) right son=3 (2487 obs)
Primary splits:
  Dag           splits as  RRLLRRR, improve=0.02478172, (0 missing)
  Hoofdberoep    splits as  RLRLLRRLLLLRLL, improve=0.02313676, (0 missing)
  Ploegenstelsel splits as  RRLRRRL, improve=0.02191660, (0 missing)
  Werksituatie   splits as  LRLR, improve=0.02179270, (0 missing)
  Werkuren       splits as  RLRRRR, improve=0.02130351, (0 missing)
```

How do I have to interpret the different 'improve values' (0.02478172,0.02313676,...) and how are they related to the complexity parameter (0.02717093)?

Comment: I've answered quite a similar question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9667122/420055). The on-line help for `rpart.control` provides additional information on how to tune the complexity parameter (`cp`) and its relation to improvement of fit.

Comment: MVPART seems to have been removed from CRAN in 2014.